# Marginal means and confidence levels per group with emmeans and geepack in R

Tags: r, emmeans

Please consider the following:

When fitting a GEE with `geepack` we receive a model that we can `predict` with new values but base R does not support GEE models to calculate the confidence intervals. To obtain confidence intervals we can use `emmeans::emmeans()`.

If the variables in the model are categorical and continuous I run into problems.

When estimating the marginal mean with `emmeans::emmeans()` I found that the marginal mean is calculated with the overall data and not the data per group.

**Question: how can I obtain the estimated mean per group including confidence intervals from a GEE model in R?**

---

Minimal reproducible example:

*Data*

```r
library("dplyr")
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library("emmeans")
#> Warning: package 'emmeans' was built under R version 3.5.2
library("geepack")

# Adding a grouping variable
pigs.group <- emmeans::pigs %>% mutate(group = c(rep("a", 20), rep("b", 9)))
```

*Fitting the model*

```r
# Fitting the model
fit <- geepack::geeglm(conc ~ as.numeric(percent) + factor(group),
                       id = source, data = pigs.group)

# Model results
fit
#> 
#> Call:
#> geepack::geeglm(formula = conc ~ as.numeric(percent) + factor(group), 
#>     data = pigs.group, id = source)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>         (Intercept) as.numeric(percent)      factor(group)b 
#>           20.498948            1.049322           10.703857 
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 29 Total (i.e. Null);  26 Residual
#> 
#> Scale Link:                   identity
#> Estimated Scale Parameters:  [1] 36.67949
#> 
#> Correlation:  Structure = independence  
#> Number of clusters:   3   Maximum cluster size: 10
```

Using `emmeans::emmeans()` to calculate the marginal means and LCL/UCL. However, the group means for `percent` are 12.9 in both groups. This is the overall observed mean of `percent` and not the group mean.

```r
# Calculating marginal means per group.
# Note that 'percent' is the same for both groups
emmeans::emmeans(fit, "percent", by = "group")
#> group = a:
#>  percent emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
#>     12.9   34.1 3.252 Inf      27.7      40.4
#> 
#> group = b:
#>  percent emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
#>     12.9   44.8 0.327 Inf      44.1      45.4
#> 
#> Covariance estimate used: vbeta 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95

# Creating new data with acutal means per group
new.dat <- pigs.group %>%
        group_by(group) %>%
        summarise(percent = mean(percent))

# These are the actual group means
new.dat
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   group percent
#>   <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 a        13.2
#> 2 b        12.3
```

Predicting with `predict` also returns other estiamted means per group, but no confidence intervals can be estimated for GEE in base R.

```r
# Prediction with new data
# These should be the marginal means but how to get the confidence interval?
predict(fit, newdata = new.dat)
#>        1        2 
#> 34.35000 44.14444
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you thought was a computing issue turns out to be a statistical one...

When you have covariates in a model, the usual approach in post hoc analysis is to control *for* those covariates. In the context of the example given, we want to compare the mean response in different groups. However, the response is also affected by the covariate, `percent`, and the mean percent differs with each group. If we just compute the marginal means for each group, those means differ in part because of the effects of `percent`.

In an extreme example, imagine a situation where the group makes no difference whatsoever, but `percent` does. Then if the mean `percent` values differ enough among groups, then we could have statistically different means, but they would be different because of the effect of `percent`, not because of the effect of `group`.

For that reason, a "fair" comparison is obtained by predicting the means at the *same* percent -- say, the overall average percent in the dataset. That is the default method used in **emmeans**, and the results are termed *adjusted means* (look it up in a design textbook).

There is a situation where it is appropriate to use different percent values, and that is the case where percent is a "mediating variable;" that is, percent falls in the causal path between treatment and response, so that `group` is believed to affect `percent` as well as the response. See the [vignette on messy data, in the subsection on mediating covariates](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/messy-data.html#mediators).

If you truly think that `percent` is a mediating covariate, then you can get separate percents like this:

```
 emmeans(model, "group", cov.reduce = percent ~ group)
```

However, in a situation where `percent` is regarded as being independent of `group`, don't do this!

Comment: I don't want marginal means at each covariate. I want marginal means for the mean of each group (here: `group`).

I tried the following with your approach and `ref_grid()`:
`summary(ref_grid(fit, at = list(percent = new.dat$percent)))`. This returned a table with the predicted margianl mean and a SE. No LCL/UCL however.

Comment: Try `emmeans(fit, “group”)`.

Comment: `emmeans(fit, "group")` returns the same marginal means as `emmeans::emmeans(fit, "percent", by = "group")` (see results of the latter in my example above). This is exactly what triggered me writing this post. I was expecting that `emmeans(fit, "group")` would use the observed (percent) mean *per group* but since I received the same results with `emmeans::emmeans(fit, "percent", by = "group")` I concluded that the results are based on the overall mean regardless of the group.